# Convert List to an ArrayList with specific order

Tags: java, lambda, collections, hashmap

What is the best way to code this:

objectsList is not an empty list. Contains many objects. This is only to illustrate the type.

```
    List<ObjectType> objectsList= Collections.EMPTY_LIST;

    ArrayList<RelatedModule> arrayWithOrder = new ArrayList<>();

    Map<Integer, RelatedModule> mappedObjects= new HashMap<>();

    objectsList.forEach(o ->
            mappedObjects.put(o.getOrder(),
                    new Dto(o.getFirstName(),
                            o.getLastName()))
    );

    for (int i = 0; i < objectsList.size(); i++) {
        arrayWithOrder.add(mappedObjects.get(i));
    }
```

Comment: Try using `TreeMap` instead of `HashMap`.

Comment: implement `Comparable` interface to your `ObjectType` class and then use `TreeMap` instead of `HashMap`

Comment: @SungJinSteveYoo Implementing Comparable is useless: the keys of the map are Integers.

Comment: @JBNizet you are right for the janneob's case. I am saying for more general cases

Comment: Is `Dto` a subclass of `RelatedModule`?

Comment: Not sure what's inconvenient with

`for (ObjectType o : objectList) {
    Dto dto = new Dto(o.getFirstName(), o.getLastName());
    mappedObjects.put(o.getOrder(), dto);
    arrayWithOrder.add(dto);
}` ?

Comment: @nullpointer Then they're in the wrong order. They need to be sorted by the order. The map isn't needed. It's only used to reorder them. (And eliminate duplicates, if any.)

Comment: Speaking of which, can there be duplicates? That's something you need to watch out for. A HashMap will eliminate them. I get the sense you don't expect there to be any duplicates, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a `TreeMap<Integer, RelatedModule>`, but, unless there are multiple objects with the same order and the intent is to only keep the last one, you can simply sort your list and then transform it:

```
List<RelatedModule> arrayWithOrder = 
    objectsList.stream()
               .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(ObjectType::getOrder))
               .map(o -> new RelatedModule(o.getFirstName(), o.getLastName()))
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is with using `sorted` or a `TreeMap` etc is that it computes in `O(n log n)` time what can be computed in `O(n)` time. In your case, you do not need to sort because you already know the order - it is determined by the `order` property.

The fastest solution is something like this:

```
RelatedModule[] arrayWithOrder = new RelatedModule[objectsList.size()];
for (ObjectType o : objectsList)
    arrayWithOrder[o.getOrder()] = new Dto(o.getFirstName(), o.getLastName());
```

You may want to then copy the result into to a new `ArrayList`.

Your original code has the optimal time complexity, but one improvement you could make is to use `collect` calls rather than `put` or `add` in a `forEach`.